# How to calculate the following probability?

Tags: elementary-probability

There are $N$ coupons numbered $1,2,\dots,N$ in a box. If $n$ coupons are taken at random, what is the probability that $M$ will be the highest number on a ticket if the drawings are made with replacements?

- The answer can be $\frac{M^n-(M-1)^n}{N^n}$.
  Because, $n$ tickets can be drawn with number at most $M$ is $M^n$. Now subtracting the cases where the number is at most $M-1$, we get the above answer.
- But why isn't the following answer correct?  $\frac{(M-1)^{n-1}}{N^n}$

We have to draw ticket no. $M$ necessarily. So now we have to draw the other $n-1$ tickets from the $M-1$ tickets with numbers less than $M$, which is $(M-1)^{n-1}$.

- Why isn't this answer correct? Where's actually the mistake? This is the place where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: That is an interesting fun sloth fact in the background of one of your images...  Seriously though... you should not need to rely on pictures of handwriting of such short mathematical expressions.  Visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type here with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  People don't like having to click on off-site images and trying to read handwriting.

Comment: @user587389: Please check that the two expressions I MathJaxified are correct.

Comment: Thank you. I was in search of such a tool with which I can type mathematical expressions.

Comment: @user587389 Don´t forget to mark questions as answered. Otherwise users are less willing to answer your questions.+

Comment: @callculus How to mark questions answered?

Comment: @user587389 Just click on the checkmark ($ \checkmark $) for your preferred answer.

Comment: Now I have got it Sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that implicitely you assume that in the remaining $n-1$ draws, you never get $M$. But you can. This makes the computation more complicated. Idea: compute the number of possibilities where the maximum is AT MOST $M$. If this is $f(M)$, then you are looking for $f(M)-f(M-1)$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Now it's clear to me.